How to get zoom levels of *running* seed commands (gwc)
I have a gwc (Geoserver 2.24.1), running a bunch of seed commands. I know I can use the REST api to get the status of my running commands.
Is there a way (preferably using REST) to see the zoomStart/zoomEnd levels of these commands?
EDIT:
By "preferably using REST", I mean: Preferably by means of querying something (log file? process params? some obscured endpoint? - whatever can be scripted).

I don't know any way without changing the source code. It would be nice if the seed request would return the task id. Now it returns only http 200 OK https://geowebcache.osgeo.org/docs/current/rest/seed.html#seeding-xml-example.

And what would you do with the task ID? The returned json array does contain it.

Capture the parameters of the seed command and save them together with the returned ID with your script.

Not sure I follow. If I run a script, I already know (or can recall) the parameters I used in it - no need to query anything. BUT if the seeding was initiated from the GUI (or someone else ran a script), then what could one do?

Actually, the seeding requests and responses go through a web server (Jetty or Tomcat), so perhaps it would be easiest to find the information that you need from the server logs. Or use a proxy server in front of GWC if it happens to allow appropriate logging easier. GWC has also its own logging mechanism https://geowebcache.osgeo.org/docs/current/troubleshooting/index.html but maybe it does not work that way with GWC that is integrated with GeoServer.

The REST API documentation, as you know, is here: https://geowebcache.osgeo.org/docs/current/rest/seed.html#querying-the-running-tasks
The documentation explains what user can get from the API:

The returned content is a JSON array of the form:
{"long-array-array":[[<long>,<long>,<long>,<long>,<long>],...]}
...
The returned array of arrays contains one array per seeding/truncate
Task. The meaning of each long value in each thread array is:
["tiles processed", "total # of tiles to process", "estimated
remaining time (in seconds)", "Task ID", "Task status"]

The user can get an unique identifier of the running task (Task ID), but unfortunately there is no way to know which parameters were used when the task was created. For example, user knows that task #3 is running and it
tries to fetch totally 2762389170 tiles, but that is all. Even the name of the layer that is seeded must be inferred from the REST endpoint ne:countries.
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XGET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/ne:countries.json

{"long-array-array":[[19872,2762389170,417024,3,1]]}*

There is one thing that I do not understand. The user interface of the GeoWebCache is showing one detail that does not come from the REST API, namely "time elapsed". Maybe the broser application has some own timer.


So, in essence, your answer is "no, not with the REST API". I have edited my question to be more clear as to what I need.
